# Get features inside a polygon from a WMS Layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5, openlayers-6

I currently implemented [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html). So I can select layer's features with a single click or box selection.

But I want to know is it possible to get features with box selection on a wms layer?

(i tried with vector layer and it's currently working).

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some information about what exactly you need, what you have done already. what do you mean "all feature inside polygon"?

Comment: it simple , means all feature in my layer . u can see example if u need 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html

Comment: Do you want to select features of a layer inside a box like the example you mentioned? and the only difference is the using layer? wms layer instead of vector layer?

Comment: yes , exactly
thank u

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of loading a layer as WMS.

> WMS can be used as a Tile layer, as shown here, or as an Image layer.

In both ways, the webserver(GeoServer) sends a tile/image to the client. The example you mentioned uses `Vector Layer`, which means server send features one by one, not an image or a tile. So you can't check the "box selection extent" and features to find Intersections.

But there is another thing that can help a bit. `GetFeatureInfo` is a solution to get features from a WMS layer. it gets a single coordinate (a click) and some other information, then return feature of that coordinate.

So answering your question. No, it's not possible to box selecting but you can get a feature by a single click.

here is [the example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html).